# SUMPRODUCT of ever-other row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The goal is to sum the total hours for a group of tasks each week. Each task has a # of hours and # of times it is done each week. I'm having a hard time articulating the topic, so I'll include a screenshot.
[image: Screenshot of tasks and hours]

I used SUMPRODUCT to get the total # hours for the year, but I'm trying to get the equivalent for each task each week.

I started down using MOD(ROW($D$8:$D$23),2)**=0**,$D$8:$D$23,0) to get the value of every other row, but I'm struggling to multiply the values from that array the values from the array provided with MOD(ROW($D$8:$D$23),2)**=1**,$D$8:$D$23,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little chance that I am willing to retype your data but you might try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((NOT(MOD(ROW($8:$22), 2))*D$8:D$22), (MOD(ROW($9:$23), 2)*D$9:D$23))
```

This returns 45 for column D. Fill right for additional columns. Note that while the ranges D$8:D$22 and D$9:D$23 are staggered by one row they contain the same rows-by-columns dimensions (e.g. 15R × 1C).